# Problem with LS-Dyna/Ansys Inlet velocity curve

Tags: ansys

I'm working with simulations for my thesis and I have some problems with Ls-Dyna. 
It is possible to assign the same velocity value  to every inlet's cell in a CFD simulation?
I'm using ICFD_Prescribed_Vel keyword for the inlet boundary condition but I'm confused about the way in which Ls-Dyna assign the values defined to the cells.